# Why does exporting a Crystal Report cause my MAPI address book to throw an excpetion?

Tags: crystal-reports, mapi

I'm experiencing a strange problem where exporting a crystal report causes problems for displaying a MAPI address book. These are two completely unrelated tasks and I don't understand how one affects the other.

This is an example of exporting the report:

```
Using rpt As New TestReport
    rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
End Using
```

This is an example of showing the MAPI address book:

```
Dim msg As New AxMSMAPI.AxMAPIMessages
Dim sess As New AxMSMAPI.AxMAPISession
Dim f As System.Reflection.FieldInfo
Const MAPI_LICENSE As String = "mgkgtgnnmnmninigthkgogggvmkhinjggnvm"

f = GetType(AxHost).GetField("licenseKey", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
f.SetValue(msg, MAPI_LICENSE)
f.SetValue(sess, MAPI_LICENSE)

sess.Parent = Me
msg.Parent = Me

sess.DownLoadMail = False
sess.LogonUI = True
sess.SignOn()
sess.NewSession = True
msg.SessionID = sess.SessionID
msg.Compose()

msg.Action = MSMAPI.MessagesActionConstants.mapShowAddressBook

sess.SignOff()
```

One strange thing is that if I show the MAPI address book first, then both exporting the crystal report and displaying the MAPI address book work for the remainder of the life of the program. If I export first, the MAPI address book does not work for the remainder of the life of the program.

The exception that gets thrown is at the following line as "Unspecified Failure has occurred" with error code "-2146796286"

```
msg.Action = MSMAPI.MessagesActionConstants.mapShowAddressBook
```

Comment: This was done with Crystal 13.0.2000.0 and MAPI 1.1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, I too have seen problems with my MAPI code and Crystal Reports. I never had a chance to figure out the ultimate cause, but in some cases querying the current folder, running a report, then restoring the current folder seemed to help.

Comment: I tried the following to no avail. Is this what you meant?

    Dim path As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
    Using rpt As New TestReport
        rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat)
    End Using
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = path